# How set font properties in calculated field using Digital-Metaphors Report Builder RAP

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I'm trying to set font attributes in a variable in Digital-Metaphors Report Builder using RAP.  The code I'm using is:

```
if (DBdetail['LINEATTR']='1') then begin
    budgetValue.font.style:=[fsBold];
end;
```

but this isn't working, I get a compile time error.  How can I set the font style?

Comment: Bill, it could be a good idea if you append 'Delphi' to the tag list.

Where are you writting this (event)?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  This is in the onprint event.

Comment: Also good to know would be the error message that you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for RAP is

Label.Font.Bold := True;

RAP does not support ‘set’ types.