# How to conditionally format ReportBuilder field in Detail band depending on the other fields in then Detail band?

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

My DBText5 contains 0 or 1 and I would like to format DBText3 depending on DBText5 - I am using code ([How set font properties in calculated field using Digital-Metaphors Report Builder RAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930773/how-set-font-properties-in-calculated-field-using-digital-metaphors-report-build)):

```
if (DBText5.FieldValue=1) then begin
  DBText3.Font.Bold := True;
end;
```

Both, DBText3 and DBText5 reside in Detail band. I have tried to put this code in the following events (of course I checked that only one event is active at each given time):

```
DBText3.OnPrint
DetailBand.OnBeforePrint
CustomVariableOnDetailsBand.Calculate
```

But in each case the DBText3 appears bold in all rows of the report. My intention is to make DBText3 bold in only those rows whose hase DBText5=1. Which event should I use or what other adaptations should I make?

Digital Metaphors own solution is to use Band.OnBeforePrint https://www.digital-metaphors.com/forums/discussion/9962/conditional-format but Detail.OnBeforePrint is not working form, as I said.

**Additional Info**: As suggested by the accepted answer - one should implement else clause as well.

Comment: Have you tried referencing the DataPipeline field value instead of DBText5.FieldValue?  I'm assuming that the BeforePrint event may not be aware the DBText5.Fieldvalue. Maybe a chicken/egg problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either - DBText3 is still bold in all the rows. If this was chicken/egg problem, the this would show ups as not-bold-at-all problem. ReportBuilder does not recognize DBText5 at the row/detail level somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a quick test project and confirmed that this works.

I'm using Report Builder 19, Build 76, and Delphi 10.2.

```
procedure TForm1.ppDetailBand1BeforePrint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DBText5.fieldvalue = 20  then
    DbText5.Font.Style := [fsBold]
  else
    DbText5.Font.Style := [];
end;
```

You need to set the style for both the true and false condition.

Since you're using RAP, you can use

```
if DbText5.Fieldvalue = 1 then
  DbText5.Font.Bold := true
else
  DbText5.Font.Bold := false;
```